# Windows 2008 IIS URL Rewrite not rewriting to index.php, Getting 404 Error instead

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, rewrite

It is not an issue with web.config, I know this because I reinstalled IIS to fix an issue.  But for completeness, here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="CakePHP" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The error in IIS:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
   The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    MapRequestHandler
Handler StaticFile
Error Code  0x80070002
```

The default action of my index.php is to redirect to login if they are not already logged in---and it's doing that, but:

So as far as I can tell, its actually redirecting to the actual directory /users/login, instead of rewriting to index.php.

I have removed/reinstalled in hopes that might fix it, it doesn't.  Whats weird is part of the rewrite is working, the 'IsFile' works, because I have a 'test.php' file in the same directory as index.php, and am able to load that.

as an update, I was going to do Failed Request Tracking:

```
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules
```

But where I got to add the rule for 'Rewrite', rewrite does not exist.  (but URL Rewrite is in the IIS Panel).

**ISSUE RESOLVED:**

This URL more or less resolved it:

```
http://forums.iis.net/t/1178209.aspx?URL+Rewrite+Module+Not+working+at+all
```

When going to the Failed Request Tracking, I also did not have 'Rewrite' as an option to select.

'Repair' in program and settings did not work for me, so I uninstalled, and then reinstalled, and I'm going!

Comment: You should make your "answer" a real answer and "Accept" it.

Comment: wouldn't allow me, otherwise I would have.